# How to fix an overdispersion in a Poisson GLMM with glmer function in R?

Tags: r, mixed-model, poisson-distribution, lme4-nlme, overdispersion

I want to model counts as being dependent on two nominal variables, one continuous variable (all as fixed effects) with 3rd-order interactions and one grouping variable (as random effect). However, I have an overdispersion in outcomes (I used the `glmer` function from `lme4` library). How should I manage this? I have found some solution for the problem (https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/9670/38080) but I am not able to incorporate that recommendation into my model.

Here is my model:

```
m1<-glmer(dependent.var ~ cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|group),
         data = dat, family = "poisson")
```

Any suggestion?
(I did it also like a marginal model with 'geeglm' function (library geepack), but **I would like to calculate R-squared of the model**, which is possible to obtain just from former GLMM (see Nakagawa & Schielzeth 2013; http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.2041-210x.2012.00261.x/abstract).)

Comment: Can you expand on the statement that you were not able to incorporate the recommendation of including `(1|subject_id)` ?

Comment: Number of measured subjects in my dataset is equal to number of observations or records in the dataset. Thus I do not know if I should incorporate both (1|subject_id) and 'data$obs_effect<-1:nrow(data)'...

Comment: You can call it `subject_id` or `obs_effect` - they are the same thing in your case. Include one of them, and any other fixed and random effects you need.

Comment: I did it like this: m1<-lmer(dependent.var ~ 1 + cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|obs_effect) + (1|group), data = dat, family = "poisson"), and also like this: m1<-lmer(dependent.var ~ 1 + obs_effect + cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|obs_effect) + (1|group), data = dat, family = "poisson") but in both cases the model residuals ('plot(fitted, residuals)') were not OK at all (they formed a triangle)...

Comment: You can use the negative.binomial() function from the MASS package in the family argument I the glmer() call. You need to supply a known value for theta though. You could run the model as a standard glm.nb() model without the random effects and use the estimated value of theta from that, though I don't know whether this approach is valid or not? Perhaps someone else can comment?

Comment: see http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#overdispersion_est ...

Comment: @Ben and @Aniko , I had used that (http://glmm.wikidot.com/faq#overdispersion_est)  function for the model:
> m1<-lmer(dependent.var ~ cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|group),  data = dat, family = "poisson")
and I have obtained  **chisq**  1.324502e+02,   **ratio** 1.379690e+00, **rdf** 9.600000e+01, and **p** 8.130703e-03.
The m1-model ‘s diagnostics graphics `f <- fitted (m1);   r <- residuals (m1);   ED <- resid (m1, type = "deviance"); plot(f, r); plot (cat.var1, r); plot (cat.var2, r); plot (contin.var, r)` - all 4 plots are OK. (To be continued.)

Comment: @Ben, thus I did 
>  m2 <- lmer(dependent.var ~  cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|obs_effect) + (1|group), data = dat, family = "poisson")

and obtained  **chisq**  66.6674549,   **ratio** 0.7017627, **rdf** 95.000, and **p** 0.9879.
However, in m2- model ‘s diagnostics, plot (f, r) has triangle-shaped scatter of residuals which decreases with the fitted values. So I am helpless now...

Comment: @BenBolker Here are posted my data: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0Bz8ojhHeiNclVi1oT0ZwTEtEN2s/edit

Answer (score 8):

Pulling out the answer from the discussion in the comments: If you create an `obs_effect` variable (observation-level random effect) with a unique value for each observation (say, `1:nrow(dat)`), then you can incorporate overdispersion in the model by fitting

```
m2 <- glmer(dependent.var ~  cat.var1 * cat.var2 * contin.var + (1|obs_effect) + (1|group),
           data = dat, family = "poisson")
```

You also state in the comments that your problem is that the residual plot is triangle-shaped, which I interpret as the variability of the residuals increases with the predicted value. Depending on what kind of residuals you are plotting, this might mean nothing (the variability of `observed - fitted` should increase with `fitted`), or might mean that you have a problem other than overdispersion, which does not show up in a residual plot.

Reference:
Harrison, X.A., 2014. [Using observation-level random effects to model overdispersion in count data in ecology and evolution](https://peerj.com/articles/616/). PeerJ 2, e616. doi:10.7717/peerj.616

Comment: thank you for your answer. The variability of residuals of m2-model decreases with fitted values. Interestingly, in overdispersed Poisson GLMM, scatter of those residuals against fitted values is OK. Please, see my last two comments above for more info.