# Should I use a mixed model for this paired design?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, lme4-nlme

I ran an experiment wherein I measured pollinator responses (the number of visits received, `total_flr_vis`) to inflorescences (flower stalks bearing multiple flowers per stalk) that were assigned to either treatment `r` or control `c` groups (collectivly, `treatment`).

This was a paired design- one stalk on each plant was assigned to each group. Each subject (individual plant, `individual`) was measured only once, testing `r` and `c` stalks simultaneously.

The number of flowers that each stalk bore at the time of the experiment (`flr_num`) varied, and is an important co-variate. That is: `total_flr_vis` is expected, *a priori*, to increase with `flr_num`.

I am not interested in the effect of `flr_num`, only the effect of `treatment`.

My question is this: what is the most appropriate way to specify this model? Should I include `individual` as a random effect in a mixed model, or is there a good way to build this without relying on a mixed design. I would prefer to avoid using a mixed model unless it is actually necessary, but I'm afraid that I don't know how else to construct this.

As of now, my best guess is to use:

```
mod = glmer(data=data, total_flr_vis ~ treatment + flr_num + (1|individual), family=poisson)
```

[But I have run into some issues with this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/273416/error-bars-overlap-but-effect-is-significant-in-glmm-whats-going-on/273426#273426)

Thank you in advance for any advice you can offer.